# Add the sum of an undefined array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, array-sum

I now this code works if I have preset values defined in my array, how would I go about doing this when the values are not defined? I have a hard time with all loops in general especially for loop.

I know there are methods to achieve this, but for the purpose of my assignment I must achieve it using a for loop.

```
function sum() {
  let input = document.getElementById("wordInput").value;
  let values = [];
  let sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    sum += values[i]

    if (values) {
      document.getElementById("resultReturned").innerHTML = " Total is" + sum;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, specifically, the values in the array are ```undefined```, or do you mean that you don't know what they are?

Comment: Something like `if (values[i] !== undefined) sum += values[i];`

Comment: I mean they ARE undefined. What ever the user inputs in the form should be calculated to equal a total sum....

Answer (score 0):

Give your function a *parameter*. This way you can pass any array to your function and loop over it, no matter the length.

```
function sum(values) {
  let input = document.getElementById("textField").value;
  let sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    sum += values[i]

    if (values) {
      document.getElementById("valueReturned").innerHTML = "The sum is" + sum;
    }
  }
}

// Call the sum function and pass an array.
sum([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example:

```js
function sumup(values) {
  // Got rid of input
  // taking values as arguments for this example
  let sum = 0;
  let res = 0; // Or whatever the default value
  if (values) {
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      sum += values[i]
      res = sum;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("valueReturned").innerHTML = "The sum is " + res;
}
sumup([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // Array passed here
// 15
```

```html
<div id="valueReturned"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're trying to solve but I'll answer the questions I believe you may be asking.

First, I'll provide a few comments on the code I'm seeing. For starters, you probably want to move that `if (values) {}` block out of the `for` loop. I'm guessing your intent is to update the DOM if there are `values`.

Second, if `values` is an array, you should look at the length of the array to determine if it is empty with something like `if (values.length > 0)`. An empty array will evaluate truthy and the DOM would be updated every time with your code as written.

Third, I'm not sure about the role of `input` here. That will give you a single value, not an array.

Here's what I would recommend, not knowing what you envision for the role of `input`:

```
function sum() {
  let input = document.getElementById("wordInput").value;
  let sum = 0;

  const values = [] // wherever values come from, perhaps a function argument or inputs

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    sum += values[i]
  }
  if (values.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("resultReturned").innerHTML = "The sum is" + sum;
  }
}
```